# Node.js server running fine but dont show nothing Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, server, backend

I deployed my simple server in heroku in my method get :

`app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});`

in the heroku logs I havent error, 
but when I go to the link only show "Method Not Allowed" and is all.

Any idea why this happens if this run is supposed to be good.

[image]

Comment: How are you accessing this url in your browser?

Comment: this is the url: https://git.heroku.com/servidor-fortuna.git

Comment: Wow its work only open de urls with `heroku open` command, and the url now is work.

Answer (score 0):

It can be CORS error, not sure but hopefully adding this code will help.

```
    if(req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE, GET, HEAD');
        return res.status(200).json({ });
    }
```